# Title missing in fc-header-center

Tags: fullcalendar

I've searched the WordPress support forum as well as here and can't figure out why the headers are invisible on the FullCalendar.  I believe it's in fc-header-center, but I could be wrong - everything I've searched for there looks right, but yet nothing is showing up.

[Here's the site I'm working on](http://csiainc.org/newsite/calendar/).  I greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks!
Taryn

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS style on the page that sets the opacity of `<h2>` elements to 0, and that's the reason that the title doesn't appear.

It seems to be the last line in this script on your page who's guilty:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var imageResize = "timthumb",
        resizeDisabled = "",
        assetsUri = "http://csiainc.org/newsite/wp-content/themes/infocus/images/assets",
        imageNonce = "6f8a12c74f",
        disableSlidemenu = "false",
        prettyphotoTheme = "pp_default",
        imagePadding = "10",
        responsiveSite = "false";
    document.write('<style type="text/css">.noscript{visibility: hidden;}.ie .noscript{visibility: collapse;}.noscript_dn{display: none;}h1,h2,h3,.additional_posts_module h4,h4,h5,.logo a,.call_to_action,#intro .intro_title,#intro .teaser,#slider_module+#intro h3,#sidebar .widgettitle,#outro,#outro a,#footer .widgettitle,.toggle a,.toggle_accordion a,#content .teaser{opacity: 0;-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}</style>');
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: I do see that.  I've also used Chrome's Inspect Element, but I don't know how to tell where the file is that holds this code for me to change it?  I tried effecting a change by just using custom css, but it didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey - I figured it out.  Thanks!